# select with multiple conditiions in where in

Tags: sql, postgresql

With tables `table1` and  `table2`need select the rows of `table1` for those `locationId`s and `hour`s where `tier` in `table2` is `high`

**table1**

```
+------------+------+---------+----------+
| locationId | hour | metric1 |  metric2 |
+------------+------+---------+----------+
|       1111 |   10 |     200 |       40 |
|       1111 |    9 |     300 |      -20 |
|       1111 |   11 |    1800 |      300 |
|       1122 |    9 |     600 |      800 |
|       1122 |   11 |    2300 |      -10 |
|       1133 |    8 |   10000 |       30 |
+------------+------+---------+----------+
```

**table2**

```
+------------+------+-------+---------+
| locationId | hour | value |   tier  |
+------------+------+-------+---------+
|       1111 |   10 |  1300 |  high   |
|       1111 |    9 |   900 |  medium |
|       1111 |   11 |   200 |  low    |
|       1122 |    9 |   100 |  low    |
|       1122 |   11 |  2300 |  high   |
|       1133 |    8 |  1400 |  high   |
+------------+------+-------+---------+
```

If it was one column - say `locationId` I could have done something like

```
select * from table1
where locationId in (select locationId from table2 where tier='high');
```

How do I do this when the `locationId`, `hour` pair need to be compared?

**output**

```
+------------+------+---------+----------+
| locationId | hour | metric1 |  metric2 |
+------------+------+---------+----------+
|       1111 |   10 |     200 |       40 |
|       1122 |   11 |    2300 |      -10 |
|       1133 |    8 |   10000 |       30 |
+------------+------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: one option is to have a column `locationId_hour`  which is concatenation of `locationId` `hour` colums added to `table2`and use `select * from table1
where locationId || hour in (select locationId_hour from table2 where tier='high')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a simple join should handle this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.locationId = t2.locationId AND
       t1.hour       = t2.hour
WHERE t2.tier = 'high'
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables.

```
select * from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.locationId =t2.locationId 
where t2.tier='high'
```

Comment: @user3206440 try this one

Answer (score 0):

Use EXISTS method to get your result :

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 TBL1 WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM table2 TBL2 WHERE TBL1.locationId = TBL2.locationId AND
  TBL1.hour = TBL2.hour AND TBL2.tier = 'high'
)
```